# In R, Filter table based on column values in a other table?

Tags: r, filter, group-by, filtering, grouping

I search here for a similar question but couldn't find the answer. Please can you help me achieve this task. I have a table with large dataset of patient records over 10,000 patients, and I have another table for just 689 patients. I would like to filter the large table to only keep records related to patients in the second table. Then create a new table grouping both tables so then I end up with three tables (Two filtered tables and one merged table).

============================ What I have now =====================

Table 1 (Relevant Patients):

```
ID  |  PatientID  | Record1 |  Record2 |  Record3
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |  7366       |  3      |  1      |     1
2   |  7362       |  3      |  1      |     1
3   |  7361       |  3      |  1      |     1
4   |  7360       |  3      |  1      |     1
5   |  7363       |  3      |  1      |     1
```

Table 2 (All Patients):

```
   ID  |  PatientID  |  Blood      | SomeRecord |  Foo
    --------------------------------------------------------
    1   |  7316       |  06668      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    2   |  7302       |  08677      | 21/08/2015 |     3
    3   |  7341       |  07787      | 21/08/2015 |     2
    4   |  7340       |  08977      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    5   |  7313       |  07887      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    6   |  7366       |  56668      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    7   |  7362       |  88677      | 21/08/2015 |     3
    8   |  7361       |  77787      | 21/08/2015 |     2
    9   |  7360       |  98977      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    10  |  7363       |  87887      | 21/08/2015 |     1
```

I would like to filter table 2 based on table one Patient ID. The group both 1 and 2 into a new table.

============================ Desired Out Put =====================

Table 2 (All Patients Now filtered):

```
   ID  |  PatientID  |  Blood      | SomeRecord |  Foo
    --------------------------------------------------------
    6   |  7366       |  56668      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    7   |  7362       |  88677      | 21/08/2015 |     3
    8   |  7361       |  77787      | 21/08/2015 |     2
    9   |  7360       |  98977      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    10  |  7363       |  87887      | 21/08/2015 |     1
```

Table 3 (All Patients Now filtered and all records grouped):

```
   ID  |PatientID|Blood|SomeRecord|Foo|Record1|Record2|Record3
    --------------------------------------------------------
    6  |  7366   |56668|21/08/2015 |1 |   3   |    1   |  1    
    7  |  7362   |88677|21/08/2015 |3 |   3   |    1   |  1    
    8  |  7361   |77787|21/08/2015 |2 |   3   |    1   |  1    
    9  |  7360   |98977|21/08/2015 |1 |   3   |    1   |  1    
    10 |  7363   |87887|21/08/2015 |1 |   3   |    1   |  1
```

Comment: I believe the vocab word you're looking for is anti-join.

Comment: I think you want to join using two fields correct?   `final_data<-merge(table2, table1, by =c("PatientID", "ID"), all.y = T)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply two joins in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(table2,table1, by=("PatientID"))
inner_join(table2,table1, by=("PatientID"))
```

**Result:**

```
> semi_join(table2,table1, by=("PatientID"))
  ID PatientID Blood SomeRecord Foo
1  6      7366 56668 21/08/2015   1
2  7      7362 88677 21/08/2015   3
3  8      7361 77787 21/08/2015   2
4  9      7360 98977 21/08/2015   1
5 10      7363 87887 21/08/2015   1
> inner_join(table2,table1, by=("PatientID"))
  ID.x PatientID Blood SomeRecord Foo ID.y Record1 Record2 Record3
1    6      7366 56668 21/08/2015   1    1       3       1       1
2    7      7362 88677 21/08/2015   3    2       3       1       1
3    8      7361 77787 21/08/2015   2    3       3       1       1
4    9      7360 98977 21/08/2015   1    4       3       1       1
5   10      7363 87887 21/08/2015   1    5       3       1       1
```

**Data**

```
table1 <-read.table(text="ID    PatientID   Record1   Record2   Record3
1     7366         3        1           1
2     7362         3        1           1
3     7361         3        1           1
4     7360         3        1           1
5     7363         3        1           1",
header=T,stringsAsFactors =F)

table2 <-read.table(text="  ID    PatientID    Blood       SomeRecord   Foo
    1     7316         06668       21/08/2015      1
    2     7302         08677       21/08/2015      3
    3     7341         07787       21/08/2015      2
    4     7340         08977       21/08/2015      1
    5     7313         07887       21/08/2015      1
    6     7366         56668       21/08/2015      1
    7     7362         88677       21/08/2015      3
    8     7361         77787       21/08/2015      2
    9     7360         98977       21/08/2015      1
    10    7363         87887       21/08/2015      1",
header=T,stringsAsFactors =F)
```

Comment: Done this but table one had 613 rows and table two had 6222 now after I used the inner_join the number of rows increased to 21046? Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `right_join` wont' work. It really should really be `inner_join`

Comment: I think it is because you have several PatientID that are duplicated.

Comment: I think you are really trying to subset on two fields "PatientID" and "ID" this is why you are not getting down to the 613 rows. But I can't be sure.

Comment: @SamanthaDS Adding "ID" will not work unfortunately. The ID for Patient 7366 is 1 in table1 and 6 in table2.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final_data<-merge(table2, table1, by =c("PatientID", "ID"), all.y = T)
```

Comment: filtered_table2<-table2[PatientID %in% table1$PatientID] Thank you for the reply but this line has increased the observations almost four times the actual number instead of filtering the table

Comment: Why are you using `data.table`?? Almost all of this is base functionality.

Comment: Are you looking for unique records on PaitentID and ID?

Comment: Not matching on "ID" that looks like an observation tally as opposed to a unique patient identifier. The OP most likely chose a bad name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table1) #convert each table _by reference_ to the data.table type
setDT(table2)
```

I actually think it's easier to accomplish your second step first.

First, the anti-join:

```
table3 <- table2[table1, on = "PatientID", nomatch = 0L]
```

We can think of this as a subset since `table1` is in `i`; it's simultaneously a merge (evidenced by the use of `on`), i.e., we merge `table1` and `table2` by `PatientID`, only keeping rows that are matched in `table1` (by activating `nomatch = 0` to drop unmatched rows)

Next, filter `table2`:

```
table2 <- table3[ ,names(table2), with = FALSE]
```

Basically, we just remove all the columns of `table1` from `table3` to get a filtered `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

**1) no packages** If DF1 and DF2 are the two data.frames then `M` and `M[1:5]` are the required outputs.  Omit the lines marked ## if sorting is not needed:

```
M <- merge(DF2, DF1[-1], by = "PatientID")

o <- order(M$ID) ##
M <- M[o, ] ##
```

giving:

```
> M[1:5]

  PatientID ID Blood SomeRecord Foo
5      7366  6 56668 21/08/2015   1
3      7362  7 88677 21/08/2015   3
2      7361  8 77787 21/08/2015   2
1      7360  9 98977 21/08/2015   1
4      7363 10 87887 21/08/2015   1

> M
  PatientID ID Blood SomeRecord Foo Record1 Record2 Record3
5      7366  6 56668 21/08/2015   1       3       1       1
3      7362  7 88677 21/08/2015   3       3       1       1
2      7361  8 77787 21/08/2015   2       3       1       1
1      7360  9 98977 21/08/2015   1       3       1       1
4      7363 10 87887 21/08/2015   1       3       1       1
```

**2) sqldf**

```
> library(sqldf)
> sqldf("select b.* from DF1 a join DF2 b using (PatientID)")

  ID PatientID Blood SomeRecord Foo
1  6      7366 56668 21/08/2015   1
2  7      7362 88677 21/08/2015   3
3  8      7361 77787 21/08/2015   2
4  9      7360 98977 21/08/2015   1
5 10      7363 87887 21/08/2015   1

> sqldf("select b.*, a.* from DF1 a join DF2 b using (PatientID)")

  ID PatientID Blood SomeRecord Foo ID PatientID Record1 Record2 Record3
1  6      7366 56668 21/08/2015   1  1      7366       3       1       1
2  7      7362 88677 21/08/2015   3  2      7362       3       1       1
3  8      7361 77787 21/08/2015   2  3      7361       3       1       1
4  9      7360 98977 21/08/2015   1  4      7360       3       1       1
5 10      7363 87887 21/08/2015   1  5      7363       3       1       1
```

**Note:**  The inputs are:

```
Lines1 <- "ID  |  PatientID  | Record1 |  Record2 |  Record3
1   |  7366       |  3      |  1      |     1
2   |  7362       |  3      |  1      |     1
3   |  7361       |  3      |  1      |     1
4   |  7360       |  3      |  1      |     1
5   |  7363       |  3      |  1      |     1"

Lines2 <- " ID  |  PatientID  |  Blood      | SomeRecord |  Foo
    1   |  7316       |  06668      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    2   |  7302       |  08677      | 21/08/2015 |     3
    3   |  7341       |  07787      | 21/08/2015 |     2
    4   |  7340       |  08977      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    5   |  7313       |  07887      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    6   |  7366       |  56668      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    7   |  7362       |  88677      | 21/08/2015 |     3
    8   |  7361       |  77787      | 21/08/2015 |     2
    9   |  7360       |  98977      | 21/08/2015 |     1
    10  |  7363       |  87887      | 21/08/2015 |     1"

DF1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
DF2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```